# Input Validation in Silverlight 4 to EF Entity

Tags: silverlight, wcf, entity-framework, validation, mvvm

I have a Silverlight application that is loading Entities from a WCF Service via DataBinding.

So I have several views with many textboxes whose textboxes contents are binded to a Entity properties.

I want to use Silverlight validation and I don't want to use the exceptions way (I have some entities with a lot of properties... and I don't want to repeat it every time I use it in a form...).

So I'm triying to use the IDataErrorInfo way, but I'm not sure how should I do it.

I think I should declare a client-side model with equivalent classes to the Service EF Model but implementing the IDataErrorInfo. This solution means duplicate the model code and make any way to translate from service model to client model.

The other solution could be to change the EF Model itself but I don't know if this is correct for the MVVM (this is really near to the view, isn't it).

Maybe there is another magical solution I don't know.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended interface is actually [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx/)

Which gives you a little more control and supports multiple errors. It's also a little bit easier to use in scenarios when you manually want to control when validation happens.

Basically, with this, you could create a validate method on your "client side" objects which goes through their properties, validates each one, and builds up a list of errors. (HasErrors becomes true, you notify `ErrorsChanged` and then the code that binds to your object does `GetErrors`.

With this way, you could build a validation engine and have each EF object poll your database for validation rules.

There's also this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335695.aspx
If you have the option of annotating your EF classes on the client side instead of simply using the generated ones, you may be able to find an easy solution here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I'll ve to use "client side" objects and replicate EF returned data...

I'll try it that way then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is slightly off-topic since you're using WCF
but if you were to use RIA Services, then it generates objects from your EF, and you can simply add some attributes to them in the RIA (it comes with comments telling you which attributes to use)
and it's very very simple.

but that advice is relevant only if you were to use RIA.